# Why is every convergent sequence bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series

consider the sequence $\left\langle\frac{1}{n-1}\right\rangle$.

This sequence is convergent but when $n=1$, $\frac{1}{1-1}$ has no bound.

Am I doing something wrong here or does the theorem **Every convergent sequence is bounded** means something else.

Comment: Presumable you are taking about a real valued sequence (and hence $n >1$ here).

Comment: Your language is confused. Boundedness is a property of sequences, but you've said "$\frac{1}{1-1}$ has no bound." This is literally meaningless: first, $\frac{1}{1-1}$ is not a sequence (and hence boundedness does not apply to it); worse still, $\frac{1}{1-1}$ doesn't even denote a real number. A sequence is a function on the positive integers. Your rule $f(n)=\frac{1}{n-1}$ does not define a sequence because it is not defined at $n=1$.

Answer (score 4):

Every convergent sequence of real numbers is bounded.  Every convergent sequence of members of any metric space is bounded (and in a metric space, the distance between every pair of points is a real number, not something like $\infty$).  If an object called $\dfrac 1 {1-1}$ is a member of a sequence, then it is not a sequence of real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence should start from $n=2$ for it to be well defined..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/556897)

Comment: ohh ok ok. thank you for your comment. I am quite a fresh user so sorry for the mistake..

Answer (score 0):

Much like an improper integral such as $\int_{a}^{∞} f(x)dx$, which converges if there exists some $a$ such that the integral gives a finite value, sequences do not have to converge starting at any given $n.$ In this case, as Prajakta notes, the sequence converges (to zero) if you start with $n \ge 2$.